# nginx not redirecting to upstream location

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, fpm

I thought I had understood the basics of nginx rewrite rules. How wrong I was.

Can you please let me know what is I am doing so wrong here:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /apps/user/websites/;

    location / {
     autoindex on;
    }
   location ~ myapp {
       try_files $uri $uri /office/myapp/api/public/index.php;
   }
   location ~\.php$ {
      try_files $uri $uri /office/fake/index.html;
#      include fastcgi.conf;
#      fastcgi_pass php-fpm-upstream;
    }
}
```

If I visit http://myserver/office The index.php is accessed, but instead of being caught by the last location (~.php$) as I thought it would, it is processed as a text file and send to the browser.
I was expecting to receive the office/fake/index.html file instead.

Thank you very much,
Andres

Comment: What the `/office` part from the `http://myserver/office` is meaning? Do you have the `/apps/user/websites/office` folder and an index file inside it? If you do have that folder/file your request would be served with that file. You don't have any php-fpm setup (it is commented out in your config) so that file would be send to the client as a plain text. If you don't have an `/apps/user/websites/office` folder you'd get a 404 error for that request since it does not fall under any of your two locations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.     /office is used because under office we have several webapps already installed.    I am trying to make myapp  to work..   Yes, I know I am commenting out the php-fpm on purspose. (I was expecting that when the first location tries index.php it would go to the second location and index.html would be rendered)

Comment: You are right, when the first location tried an `index.php` it goes to the second location when the second `try_files` directive tried the same file and since those file exists, sent it to the client. If you'd had something like `try_files /path/to/non/existent/file /office/myapp/api/public/index.php;` in your second location you'd finished up with the `/office/myapp/api/public/index.php` file.

Comment: BTW trying the same file several times like `try_files $uri $uri ...` is meaningless, it is just an extra system `stat()` call (which takes a valuable resources on the high-load servers). The `try_files $uri $uri/ ...` directive means check for the fie existence, if not, check if the `$uri` is a directory name and if there are some index file in that directory.

Comment: One more thing to mention, even that `try_files /path/to/non/existent/file /office/myapp/api/public/index.php;` directive would cost you an extra system `stat()` call. But there is a way to go without any performance penalty using `/dev/null` instead of `/path/to/non/existent/file` (that excellent recipe was founded [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/908086/nginx-directly-send-from-location-to-another-named-location/965779#965779)).

Comment: Ivan,   correct...it was a typo, I have the correct try_files on my setup.  Anyways,  I had been changing the file by the time you first responded  and I had realized that the redirection to the third location was not happening apparently because I am using an incorrect regexp expression, (~  myapp)  ...If I create a location like ( ~ /office/fakeapp )  and inside a redirection to index.php,  the third location takes control correctly...I am not sure if it is because the way I have it defined  in this post, the second location swallows everything (even the redirection to index.php)

Comment: Not sure I'm understand all what you said :) If you have a question about some different configuration behavior upon various requests, I think it should be another question. I hope this one behavior is being answered.

Comment: `location ~ myapp { ... }` would match any request containing `myapp` substring like `/office/myapp/`, `/office/non-myapp/` and even the `/123myapp456.html`.

Comment: Sorry if I added more confusion to the question:  Let me try again:  1- the try_files are correctly written in the file (try_files $url $uri/  <file I want to redirect the request to>.    In both locations (2nd and 3rd)....2nd Location do not redirect to 3rd location....so I never got rendered the index.html,  I just keep getting the index.php as a text file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224288/discussion-between-misterwalrus-and-ivan-shatsky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex matching locations are checked in the same order they are appeared in the config file. Having the

```
location ~ myapp {
    try_files $uri $uri /office/myapp/api/public/index.php;
}
```

before the

```
location ~\.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri /office/fake/index.html;
#    include fastcgi.conf;
#    fastcgi_pass php-fpm-upstream;
}
```

would give you an endless loop on every URI containing `myapp` substring (except those that are matching existed files and not ended with `.php`) because the `/office/myapp/api/public/index.php` URI matches the `myapp` regex. You should swap those locations in order to get this configuration workable.